# How does Minecraft address specific blocks?

Tags: minecraft, mesh, procedural

So Minecraft uses procedural meshes, how do they address a specific block? How can they separate a stone block from a dirt block?

Minecraft is just an example. I want to now how it works technically.

Comment: See [`Block.getType`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/Block.html#getType()).

Comment: that's not exactly what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the block models, as in how the textures are layered over them, Minecraft uses a `.json` file as a model as of the newest Minecraft version, 1.8.  An example of the `.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "ambientocclusion": false,
    "textures": {
        "particle": "blocks/glass",
        "glass": "blocks/glass",
        "obsidian": "blocks/obsidian",
        "beacon": "blocks/beacon"
    },
    "elements": [
        {   "__comment": "Glass shell",
            "from": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "to": [ 16, 16, 16 ],
            "faces": {
                "down":  { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" },
                "up":    { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" },
                "north": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" },
                "south": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" },
                "west":  { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" },
                "east":  { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#glass" }
            }
        },
        {   "__comment": "Obsidian base",
            "from": [ 2, 0.1, 2 ],
            "to": [ 14, 3, 14 ],
            "faces": {
                "down":  { "uv": [ 2,  2, 14, 14 ], "texture": "#obsidian" },
                "up":    { "uv": [ 2,  2, 14, 14 ], "texture": "#obsidian" },
                "north": { "uv": [ 2, 13, 14, 16 ], "texture": "#obsidian" },
                "south": { "uv": [ 2, 13, 14, 16 ], "texture": "#obsidian" },
                "west":  { "uv": [ 2, 13, 14, 16 ], "texture": "#obsidian" },
                "east":  { "uv": [ 2, 13, 14, 16 ], "texture": "#obsidian" }
            }
        },
        {   "__comment": "Inner beacon texture",
            "from": [ 3, 3, 3 ],
            "to": [ 13, 14, 13 ],
            "faces": {
                "down":  { "uv": [ 3, 3, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" },
                "up":    { "uv": [ 3, 3, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" },
                "north": { "uv": [ 3, 2, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" },
                "south": { "uv": [ 3, 2, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" },
                "west":  { "uv": [ 3, 2, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" },
                "east":  { "uv": [ 3, 2, 13, 13 ], "texture": "#beacon" }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

All blocks models are made in files like this that can be modified by the player.  The game then goes in and reads them, creating the models from the `.json` data.  There are [several 3rd party programs that assist in making of these files.](http://www.mrcrayfish.com/tools.php?id=mc)

If you are interested in seeing how the `.json` file is read, a great program for decompiling Minecraft is the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://www.modcoderpack.com), another 3rd party program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to see how Minecraft distinguishes a stone block, from a dirt block, for example, they do it like so:

1. The actual blocks themselves are stored in a big class called Blocks (https://pastebin.com/ykjkBmxv), which are then registered, then if Minecraft wants to check what block you are looking at, it can just cast a raycast from the player towards the block, then Minecraft checks the loaded chunk data, to find the block at the position.
2. Minecraft also has `.json` files for configuring how the block looks, which look like so:

```json
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "all": "blocks/dirt"
    }
}
```

Minecraft also has `blockstate` `.json` files, which are used to define variants of a block, for example, a saplings growth states.